# NameError: name 'stopwords' is not defined

Tags: python, nlp, stop-words

I'm getting the error `NameError: name 'stopwords' is not defined` for some reason, even though I have the package installed. I'm trying to do natural language processing on some feedback reviews. The `dataset` object is a table with two columns, `Reviews (a sentence of feedback)` and target variable `Liked (1 or 0)`.  Help appreciated, thanks!

---

Block 1

```
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

Output 1

```
   > [nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to

   > [nltk_data]     /Users/user/nltk_data...

   > [nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!

   > Out[14]: True
```

Block 2

```
dataset['Review'][0]
review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ' ,dataset['Review'][0])
review = review.lower()
review = review.split()
review = [word for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')] **ERROR ON THIS LINE**
```

Output 2

```
>NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-8d0ee1fd7c7f> in <module>()
      3 review = review.lower()
      4 review = review.split()
----> 5 review = [word for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')]

><ipython-input-16-8d0ee1fd7c7f> in <listcomp>(.0)
      3 review = review.lower()
      4 review = review.split()
----> 5 review = [word for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')]

>NameError: name 'stopwords' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you have from nltk.corpus import stopwords ??

Comment: @Nabin Oh wow, it worked! Thanks very much. The tutorial I was following didn't have that, but it worked for them, strange... Thanks again!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you just have to add the following line before using `stopwords` in your code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Comment: Thanks Panna! The tutorial I was following didn't have that so I thought it was a bit strange.

Comment: Don't thank me my friend, it's us helping each other :)

Comment: @PannaDas Hey, I know you answered this years ago lol but why doesn't NLTK automatically import "stopwords()"?

Comment: @MollyTaylor this is called explicit import, you can read up further and see other ways one can make imports in python. Another way you could've done this is as below:
import nltk
stpwrds = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

search "Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python" on realpython for further explanation